# while doing untar of .gz file, file untarred and created as local copy is not having the lastmodified time of original file available of .gz

Tags: java, gzip, tar, apache-commons

Is there a way to read time stamp of file in tar File format so that the same time can be set for untarred file.

For example : Tar file has multiple files in it and I want to read the last modified timestamp for a file.

Please find code below used.

I am using apache commons : commons-compress-1.2.jar

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream; 
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 

import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry; 
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream; 
import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream; 

public class UnTar { 

public static void uncompressTarGZ(File tarFile, File dest) throws IOException { 
dest.mkdir(); 
TarArchiveInputStream tarIn = null; 

tarIn = new TarArchiveInputStream( 
new GzipCompressorInputStream( 
new BufferedInputStream( 
new FileInputStream( 
tarFile 
) 
) 
) 
); 

TarArchiveEntry tarEntry = tarIn.getNextTarEntry(); 

// tarIn is a TarArchiveInputStream 
while (tarEntry != null) {// create a file with the same name as the tarEntry 
System.out.println("********"+tarEntry.getName()); 
File destPath = new File(dest, tarEntry.getName()); 
System.out.println("working: " + destPath.getCanonicalPath()); 
if (tarEntry.isDirectory()) { 
destPath.mkdirs(); 
} else { 
if(destPath.getName().endsWith(".xml") || destPath.getName().endsWith(".tp2")){ 
byte[] header = new byte[10]; 
tarIn.read(header); 
int timestamp = header[4] & 0xFF | 
(header[5] & 0xFF) << 8 | 
(header[6] & 0xFF) << 16 | 
(header[7] & 0xFF) << 24; 

destPath.setLastModified(timestamp); 
destPath.createNewFile(); 
destPath.setLastModified(tarEntry.getLastModifiedDate().getTime()); 
//byte [] btoRead = new byte[(int)tarEntry.getSize()]; 
byte [] btoRead = new byte[1024]; 
//FileInputStream fin 
// = new FileInputStream(destPath.getCanonicalPath()); 
BufferedOutputStream bout = 
new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destPath)); 
int len = 0; 

while((len = tarIn.read(btoRead)) != -1) 
{ 
bout.write(btoRead,0,len); 
} 

bout.close(); 
btoRead = null; 
} 
} 
tarEntry = tarIn.getNextTarEntry(); 
} 
tarIn.close(); 

} 

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
File tarFile = new File("D:/1_RealDoc_Classic/Work/RDC_927_ReconcileVendor_Util/Production_Samples/FSM_Files/ocwenamf.20150107210002.tar.gz"); 
File dest = new File("D:/1_RealDoc_Classic/Work/RDC_927_ReconcileVendor_Util/Production_Samples/FSM_Files/UnZipped"); 
uncompressTarGZ(tarFile, dest); 
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but to set the modify time of the .tar.gz file to the latest modify time of the files archived within, I use this:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
# set the mod time of a .tar.gz file to the mod time of the latest file within
foreach x ( $* )
  touch -t `tar tvz --full-time -f $x |& egrep -v '^tar' | awk '{ print $4, $5 }' | sort | tail -1 | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/-//g' | sed 's/://' | sed 's/:/./'` $x
end
```